# Magento 1.9 - how to change order stage email template?

Tags: magento-1.9, order-status, order-email

How can i change the order when email to be send depending on order status, for example i would like to send one when order is saved(new order), then one when order is dispatched. Not on every status change.

At this moment customers receiving emails on order creation, order confirmation, picking products, dispatching ... far too many.
Is there an option to configure sending email on certain stages?

Answer (score 1):

you can stop emails for various status:
Go to Admin->System->Configuration->Sales->Sales Emails

e.g. For order email ->
change setting Enabled - NO

and here you will see various mail sending setting with different status

[image]

You can do it in same way for Invoice,shipment....etc

Comment: Yes thank you, i just found it and it seems to do what I wanted.

Comment: Apparently not, it stopped sending updates but instead of just this is not sending Shipment email as well which is bad :( Somehow Magento is not recognizing this state ? weird. I was sure that Magento selects template according to the order state so If i disabled update it will send ship/dispatch emails anyway. Any ideas ?